# Kendo ui Grid Hierarchy error on grid.AddRow() when there is an enum column in grid

Tags: user-interface, enums, grid, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid Hierarchy and an entity which has one enum property and some other properties with other .net primitive types and also there is a toolbar button named AddNewRecord on grid. When the user presses the AddNewRecord button, it must add a new row to grid and shows a partial view in the grid (because it is Hierarchy Grid). When I comment the enum property in entity, everything works perfect; otherwise, the AddNewRecord button does nothing at all.
Does anybody know what the problem is?
Thanks in advance

```
.ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Custom().Text("AddNewRecord").Url("#").HtmlAttributes(new {@class="testClass"}))
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("EntityTemplate")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model => model.Id("Id"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("BaseInfoGeneralForm", "BaseInfo"))

    $(".testClass").click(function () {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.addRow();
        $(".k-grid-edit-row").appendTo("#grid tbody");//Add New Row
        grid.expandRow(grid.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());//Expand newly added row


public class FileStatus : EntityBase
{
    public FileStatus()
    {
    }

    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual Status Ended { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what does the Firebug console tell you?

Answer (score 0):

```
}
   this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row")[0]);
   this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row")[1]);
   this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row")[2]);
   this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row")[3]);
   this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row")[4]);
},
```